# My Google Now App does not speak

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, audio, google-now, voice-recognition

I tried out the Google Now feature that comes with Jelly Bean and it's not working as I expected. It answers my questions as a search result but does not show the exact result as a card nor does it speak to me.

I am using a Galaxy Nexus and 4.1.1 Jelly Bean. I checked the audio volume and I enabled Google Now. How can I get it to speak results to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Google Now. Go to `Settings > voice`. Change the 'speech output' option.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but after updating it works well. Just update Google Search in the Google Play Store.